# How to prove this integral, integration theory

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Given $1\le p\le\infty$ and $f \in L^{p}([0.\infty))$, prove $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-nx}dx=0$.

If $p=1$, I can use Dominated Convergence theorem directly because $f(x)e^{-nx} \rightarrow 0 \quad a.e.$ and $|f(x)e^{-nx}| \le |f(x)| \in L^{1}$.

But how about $1\lt p$ ?

Comment: If $p>1$ this is immediate from Holder's inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $q$ be defined by $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. $e^{-nqx}$ is integrable for all $n\ge 1$, i.e. $e^{-nx}$ belongs to the conjugate space $(L_q)$ of $L_p$.  Therefore $\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-nx}dx$ exists.

To get the $0$ limit, $|\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-nx}dx|\le (\int_0^\infty|f(x)|^pdx)^\frac{1}{p}(\int_0^\infty e^{-qnx}dx)^\frac{1}{q}\to 0$   since the $q$ integral term =$(\frac{1}{nq})^\frac{1}{q}\to 0$, as $n\to \infty$.